# iOS Development: How to dynamically fill a 'label' field in swift from a model?

Tags: ios, swift, api, mvvm, model

Here is [my code on GitHub that **has screen shots** of what I am trying to accomplish and what I currently have](https://github.com/kessenma/API-filling-a-table-in-swift).

I followed [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0H78ktM97yU) to come up with what I have now.

[Using data from this api](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos), I have built a table via importing the data from a model.swift file and the built in JSON parser. Now I am trying to let user view more information about the title they selected. This api has data that looks like this:

```
    [
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "delectus aut autem",
        "completed": false
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
        "completed": false
      },
...cont...
]
```

Right now I think the way to get to where I want to be is by adding in a 'cocoatouch class' view controller, and adding in code to this file to alter the label field. However, I am not sure what kinda code to add into this cocoatouch class view controller titled 'title_details_ViewController.swift'. I know that it has to connect to my file titled 'Model' somehow...

Answer (score 0):

For Detail screen, like you mentioned you need an another ViewController like DetailViewController, and you can initialize the detailVC in didSelectRowAt method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = list[indexPath.row]
        
        let viewController(detailItem: item)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
```

You can define your Detail screen like below

```
    DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var detailItem: Item!
    
    convenience init(detailItem: Item) {
        self.init()
        self.detailItem = detailItem
    }
}
```